# $w(T)=0 \implies T=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be  a complex Hilbert space. Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$.

> It is true that for an arbitrary operator $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, we have
>   $$w(T) := \sup\big\{\;\left|\langle Tu\;|\;u\rangle \right|,\;\;u \in E\;, \left\| u \right\| = 1\;\big\}=0\Longrightarrow T=0?$$
>   Or $T$ must be self-adjoint operator?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you change the conteain of the question as you already have an answer for the oder question? that is unfair

Comment: In addition, the dimension of the space plays no role.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question

Comment: @CalvinKhor the OP just change to infinite dimension as we gave an answer to to finite dimension. why?

Comment: I change my question because it is written ''$⟨Tu|u⟩$  is a diagonal matrix element''

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that you have the polarization identity

$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{4} i^{-k}\langle T(u+i^k v), u+i^k v\rangle = \langle Tu, v\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I don't understant is the answer is true or false.

Comment: @Student, if $w(T)=0$ then the above equality tells that $\langle Tu,v\rangle=0$ for all $u,v\in E$. From this you can easily deduce that $T=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\langle Tu|u\rangle$ is a diagonal matrix element, in the right basis. Is it true a matrix with all diagonal elements zero is the zero matrix? No, for example consider an operator which acts as $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ on a 2-dimensional subspace and zero on its complement. It satisfies the criterion in the question, but is not the zero matrix.

However it should be true for all diagonalizable matrices, and all normal operators on Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you but $E$ is  an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space

Comment: @Student that doesn't change the answer. If it fails to be true in finite dimensions, it can only fail harder in infinite dimensions. Infinite dimensions include all the complexities of finite dimensional linear algebra, plus some limit cases.

Comment: Thank you . But why for a normal operator we get the result?

Comment: @Student because a normal operator is diagonalizable. I am thinking of how to prove it without using the spectral theorem. I will edit my answer

Comment: Except that matrix does _not_ satisfy the condition. $T(1,1) = (1,0)$, so $<T(1,1),(1,1)> = 1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well crap. Maybe the claim _is_ true

Comment: The answer just posted by Sangchul Lee shows that it is true for all operators. Whew. I shall delete my answer.