# Equivalent condition for being Positive element of a C*-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras

This is a problem from the book "A course in functional analysis" by John B. Conway (Chapter 8 Exercise 8.9).

If $\mathcal A$ is an unital $\textit C^*$-algebra. For $a\in \mathcal A$, $a\ge 0$ if and only if $f(a)\ge 0$ for every state $f$.

One side is trivial from definition. The problem is to prove the other direction. If I can prove $a$ is self-adjoint then I am done, because for every $\lambda$ in spectrum of $a$ there is a state such that $f(a)=\lambda$.
I couldn't show it is self adjoint.

Comment: If $a$ isn't self-adjoint, then $(a-a^*)/2i$ is nonzero and self-adjoint.

Comment: Is it not possible that $f(\frac{a-a*}{2i})=0$ for all  states.?

Comment: No, because of the penultimate sentence in your question.

Comment: Ok thanks @ruy now I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically Theorem 3.4.3. in [Murphy's book](https://books.google.hr/books/about/C_Algebras_and_Operator_Theory.html?id=omviBQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y#:%7E:text=It%20is%20a%20field%20that,with%20operator%20theory%20is%20required.).

Let $\pi : \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{B}(H)$ be a faithful nondegenerate representation of $\mathcal{A}$ on a Hilbert space $H$. For a fixed unit vector $x \in H$ consider the functional $$f : A \to \Bbb{C}, \quad f(b)=\langle \pi(b)x,x\rangle.$$
It is easy to see that $f$ is a state so we have $0\le f(a) = \langle \pi(a)x,x\rangle$. In particular, we see that $$\langle \pi(a)x,x\rangle 
\ge 0, \quad \forall x \in H$$
which [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2576899/144766) that $\pi(a)$ is self-adjoint and then $\pi(a) \ge 0$.

Now we have $\pi(a) = \pi(a)^* = \pi(a^*)$ so by faithfulness we get $a = a^*$. You can also get $a \ge 0$ automatically if you recall that $\pi(\mathcal{A}_+) = \pi(\mathcal{A})_+$ holds.